# building a cortana skill that can save user speech on a path

Tags: botframework, cortana-skills-kit

Is their a way to build a cortana skill that can save whatever user spoke on a path? Im currently trying to find a way out but unable to find one

Comment: Please explain what is 'speech on a path'?

Comment: Are you trying to build a bot using the Microsoft Bot Framework?

Comment: @EricDahlvang - It's possible that he wants to save the user's speech as a sound file

Comment: Are you still working on this?